# Disagree with Low Quality review audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, low-quality-posts

I failed this [Low Quality review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/795095).

I wouldn't say this fulfills the community rules for asking a good question: No research, no given example, no attempt to solve the issue, not exactly clear to me where the problem is.

But the review tells me I'm wrong because 8 people liked the question.

**So posting such a question is ok while hopefully enough people like it?**

My response to the question as it is right now would be "open an editor like e.g. nano and start typing"

I wanted to recommend close but including the comment "Too broad".

Answer (score 9):

Here were my thoughts on loading the link.

- Bloody hell, that's short. Maybe Hugo's onto someth...
- Hang on, that's an interesting problem.

This is certainly reflective of my personal interests but scripting and programming is my $DAYJOB and silly little problems like this are the sort of nonsense that hold things up. Having it asked, and answered **makes the internet better**. Removing it doesn't.

In terms of quality, **it *is* short, but not too short.**, Note again that this is something that I *do* professionally, but I understood the question, the potential need for the question (without any requirement for explanation or whatever "research" looks like), and I understood that the answer needn't be constrained by anything other than running under Bash, on Ubuntu.

They just want to keep a log of how many times their script was run.

I'm even tempted to add an answer now.

But I'm a geek. I think we have to accept that not all questions are going to be suitable or appeal to every audience.  Sorry, I think the audit was right.

---

By extension, don't worry that you failed an audit. The review system is designed to balance the response to borderline questions just like this, in a way that raw close votes just don't handle well.

Answer (score 4):

I am not good at reviewing but if we look at this special case the other way round we have to admit that this question:

- is resolved, i.e. has an accepted answer
- has many upvotes not only to the question but also to answers
- is well recognized with 647 views as today
- has a potential to help others because of the nice answer it has

So, irrespect of what the question may have been or looked like in the first place when it was asked 3 weeks ago, what would you want to do with it today?

For low quality posts we have two options:

- **Deletion.** This is excluded mainly because of good answers but also because of upvotes, favs and lack of downvotes. And most importantly it does not harm in any way.
- **Edit for improvement.** This may be an option, but as it is an old question it may not lead to better answers or being recognized better. It would be much work - little outcome.

If it were not for a review audit we all would probably have seen no reason to touch this question. Everything else would be nitpicking, and this is not what reviews are for.

And yes, if 8 other people liked a question it can't be so bad.

Comment: Yes that's true I admit but in the review I didn't see what is upvoted or the other answers nor the date it was posted. So I didn't make a decision what would I do after having this information but what would I do if this was a new question. And I still think the user put no effort in it.

Comment: @derHugo: yeah that is a common problem with the review audits.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: We all fail audits every now and then (and it *stays* frustrating no matter how much rep you get) but in the end you get to "smell" them and then you just open the original in a new tab, look that over and then it becomes obvious that it's an audit and then you just vote the same reason as the original (Keep open / close / whatever...)